# open eclipse perspective in eclipse from command line

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp

I want to open eclipse application and pass perspective ID in it through command line.

so that eclipse opens and show the perspective

How can I do that ?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585377/how-to-show-our-own-perspective-as-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just add a command line switch of **-perspective {name}**.

[You can look at a command line switch reference here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html).

Comment: name here is the perspective Id