# how to show our own perspective as default?

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I want to know how to use our own perspective as default? it means show the perspective when the eclipse lunched. Can anyone knows how to do this ?

Comment: Question is not yet answered.
Is there way to set default for all users?

Answer (score 3):

You can select perspective with the following command line parameter

`-perspective perspectiveId`

See the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) for more information about command line parameters.

Comment: Could you give some more details? Do you get any error message?

Comment: i run the rcp, programs arguments as follows: -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog -perspective xx

Comment: Do you get any error message? Are you sure you are using the correct perspecitve id?

Comment: there is no error message, perspective id is correct. i run the rcp as a product. click the "run as", then click "run configuration", in the config view, select "Arguments" tab, and set "Program arguments:" as follows: -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog -perspective mobiletalk.ui.perspective, but it don't work. default perspective is Resources perspective