# Open specific Eclipse perspective from command line

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to set a few different shortcuts (Windows), such that each opens Eclipse in the right perspective.
The documentation (and [this SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722687/open-eclipse-perspective-in-eclipse-from-command-line)) states this should be done using:

```
eclipse -perspective <perspectiveId>
```

I've tried either using names, or numbers for "perspectiveId", and I always get the last perspective opened.
Has anyone successfully ran Eclipse into a specific perspective from the C/L?
  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse 4.2 or 4.3 this appears to be Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377981 which is marked as fixed in 4.4M2

Comment: Thanks, I am using 4.2 (Juno)